# Filtering by keyword (string) in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have a data visualization in PowerBI that is powered by SQL on the back-end. I have one particular field that I'd like to be able to filter by string-matching.  Here's what the field looks like:

```
me_drug_occurence
AB
C
ABC
BC
B
```

Each letter is unique and stands for a type of drug. More letters = combinations of drugs. No letter repeats more than once for a record. I want to use the "Filters on the page" option and have the user be able to filter by drug A, B, and C. By selecting A, for example, that would show any record that contains A (records `AB, ABC,)`.  Selecting A and B would show any record which contains A OR B (records `AB, ABC, BC, B`).  And so on and so forth.

My issue is that there doesn't seem to be an out-of-the-box way to do this in Power BI?  If I simply drag this column to the "filters on this page" sidebar, I just get options to filter by the different drug combinations.

[image]

If I choose "advanced filter", I can get closer to my goal, but it forces the user to put the keywords in manually:

[image]

So, my question is how can I accomplish a filter on this visualization that would look something like this:

```
Filter:
A
B
C
```

Where you could filter by any record that contained A, B, or C, or some combination thereof.  Do I need to create a custom measure?

Answer (score 0):

You already are on right path.
Use Advanced filtering.
In this use OR condition 
I.e 
drug contains C or drug contains B or drug contains A

This will filter out your records with only those which have either of above 3 condition matched.

Edit:
This is closest I could come up with your req.

1 Use slicer, for this slicer add filed drug occurence make it dropdown and searchable.
Now as a end user I will type in A so i get N no of records which will contain A.
As I user I will select all those records as screenshot below

[image]

and then If I type C it will show as below and select them as well

[image]

This will be the result

[image]

2. Now there is one filter on market place called Text Filter. Import it from marketpalce and there you can search like text (contains) but there you cannot add three different conditions. It will look something like below

Without text filter
[image]

After adding text for filter

[image]

Comment: But I want the user to be able to filter from a pre-set list of options: A,B,C etc, in checkboxes.  I don't want them to have to type the name of the keyword they are searching for.

Comment: Edited with some more ideas.